In Elastic Beanstalk, is my configured Nginx service per instance or global?
Is the Nginx service I configure in my Elastic Beanstalk platform a global service (and acting like a load balancer) or per instance (and acting only like a reverse proxy)?
EG:
DNS -> Nginx -> Some Instance's Server

or
DNS -> Elastic Beanstalk Internal Load Balancer -> Some Instance's Nginx -> Some Instance's Server


Elastic Beanstalk uses nginx as the reverse proxy to map your application to your Elastic Load Balancing load balancer on port 80. Elastic Beanstalk provides a default nginx configuration that you can either extend or override completely with your own configuration. This one is applied only to the environment. So the configs that you change would be applying to all instances that are created on the Elastic Beanstalk environment. So it is not platform global service. It is attached to the environment basically. But when you change the config it is there on the deployment.

So basically what I meant here is if we need to change the config we need to add the nginx config change on our source code under .platform folder with the folder structure they provide. So when we do the deployment this config file would be copied to the instances on the environment on the startup of the instance.
